# How do I show autocomplete for Bootstrap in ColdFusion template

Tags: autocomplete, coldfusion, twitter-bootstrap-4, coda, coldfusion-2016

I'm using Coda 2 and am starting a new site with Bootstrap implemented.
With all of the classes it's good to have the autocomplete suggestions while coding.
For some reason, I don't get any when coding on a ColdFusion `.cfm` file.
Does anyone know why this is and how to get it working?
With the static `.html` files it works as expected.
I have activated the option 'Suggest completions from all Site files' in Coda but that then just shows me all the functions there are somewhere on the site.

Comment: I am not familiar with Coda but if it works with HTML files then you could begin with your ColdFusion templates as HTML files. Once you are done getting autocomplete to work on the HTML files, change them to CFM files and add your CFML code. I realize this is not ideal but it might get you going at least.

Comment: A workaround would be to copy the compiled bootstrap.css into the <style> on each html file. Did you come up with a better solution?